# SQL Query - 2 queries involving COUNT() and the owner's of a certain trip

Tags: sql, count, oracle-xe

My Databases look like so:

**PEAK (NAME, ELEV, DIFF, MAP, REGION)**
**CLIMBER (NAME, SEX)**
**PARTICIPATED (TRIP_ID, NAME)**
**CLIMBED (TRIP_ID, PEAK, WHEN)**

- PEAK gives info about the mountain peaks that the user is interested in. The table lists the name of each peak, it elevation(in ft), its difficulty level(on a scale of 1-5), the map that it is located on, and the region of the Sierra Nevada that it is located in.
- CLIMBER lists the members of club, and gives their name and gender.
- PARTICIPATED gives the set of climbers who participated in each of the various climbing trips. The number of participants in each trip varies.
- CLIMBED tells which peaks were climbed on each climbing trip, along w/ the data that each peak was climbed.

I need help w/ writing an SQL query for these 2 example scenarios:

- Which peaks have been climbed by Mark and Mary?
- On which trips did the total elevation gained by all participants exceed 500,000 feet?

This is what I have for the first query:

```
SELECT PEAK
FROM CLIMBED
WHERE TRIP_ID IN
    (SELECT TRIP_ID
     FROM PARTICIPATED
     WHERE NAME IN ('MARK','MARY')
     GROUP BY TRIP_ID
     HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
    );
```

The problem w/ this query is it only gives me all of the peaks that Mark and Mary have climbed during the same trip they took together. I need to somehow get the peaks that they both have climbed, but that they weren't together for.

For the second query I have no clue how to get the COUNT() of each peak that all the participants climbed during the specific TRIP_ID.

Comment: For the first query I meant to be specific in saying that I need to be able to grab all of the Peaks that either Mark and Mary have climbed excluding the ones that either Mark climbed and Mary didn't or Mary climbed and Mark didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you should just be able to remove the Having clause to get climbs where either Mark or Mary participated.

```
SELECT PEAK
FROM CLIMBED
WHERE TRIP_ID IN
    (SELECT TRIP_ID
     FROM PARTICIPATED
     WHERE NAME IN ('MARK','MARY')
     GROUP BY TRIP_ID
    );
```

Leaving the Having clause there means that you need both Mark and Mary to be in the Participated table for a particular trip for the trip_id to give you the 2 rows mandated by the having clause.

To get the peaks where one has climbed, but not the other, use your original query, but change the having clause to be 1:

```
SELECT PEAK
FROM CLIMBED
WHERE TRIP_ID IN
    (SELECT TRIP_ID
     FROM PARTICIPATED
     WHERE NAME IN ('MARK','MARY')
     GROUP BY TRIP_ID
     HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    );
```

This works because given the where condition, Count(*) will be:

- 0 if nither of them climbed (hypothetical - the where condition will not allow this row to show)
- 1 if one of them climbed
- 2 if both of them climbed

Having clauses limit queries based on conditions after grouping, so usually are based on aggregates like Count(*), which will give you the number of records that are "contained" within each grouping.

The second question is a little tougher, but if I understand it correctly you should be able to use something like this:

```
SELECT climbed.trip_id, sum(peak.elev) 
FROM climbed LEFT JOIN participated ON climbed.trip_id = participated.trip_id
LEFT JOIN peak ON climbed.peak = peak.name
GROUP BY climbed.trip_id
HAVING sum(peak.elev) > 500000;
```

This works because using the left join, the elevation for each climber is duplicated; then when you sum for each trip, it adds the elevation for each climber.

Comment: The first query gives me all of the Peak that either Mark or Mary have climbed. But is there a way to show only the Peaks that Mark and Mary have both climbed including the similar peaks that they climbed during different trips.

Comment: Second query works exactly as expected though. Thank you!

Comment: @Scott Let me know if the fixes I made worked for you.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense, I was kinda of looking for something w/ a little different tweak but you're way works better for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: You're trying to achieve an exclusive or, which doesn't really have a keyword in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
    This is for your first query :

    Select c.NAME 
    from PARTICIPATED a
    // join with Climbed to get only peak based trips
    inner join CLIMBED b
    on a.TRIP_ID=b.TRIP_ID
    // join with peak to ge the name of peak
    inner join PEAK c
    on c.NAME=b.PEAK
    // on the result set, filter the results for specific persons only 
    where a.Name in ('Mary','Mark')
```

Answer (score 1):

> Which peaks have been climbed by Mark and Mary?

On different trips:

```
SELECT c.peak
FROM climbed c
JOIN participated p
   ON c.trip_id = p.trip_id
WHERE p.name IN('mark','mary')
```

> On which trips did the total elevation gained by all participants
>   exceed 500,000 feet?

```
SELECT c.trip_id, SUM(pe.elev)
FROM climbed c
JOIN peak pe
   ON c.peak = pe.name
JOIN participated pa
   ON c.trip_id = pa.trip_id
GROUP BY c.trip_id
HAVING SUM(pe.elev) > 500000
```